# How to create schema for another database in sql-server by Java, and keep current database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have to create database, schema, table, cascade, in sql-server, by Java, and **keep current database**.

For database and table, it's ok without changing the current db, by

`createStatement("create database NEW_DATABASE").execute();`

and

`createStatement("create table NEW_DATABASE.NEW_SCHEMA.NEW_TABLE(COLUMNES...)").execute();`

But for the schema, could not find a way to do so. I know

```
use NEW_DATABASE;
go
create schema NEW_SCHEMA;
```

would create `NEW_DATABASE.NEW_SCHEMA`, but don't know how to execute in Java, and sadly this changes current database, too.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use java code for this.Do you want to create a database and a table at runtime?

Comment: Yes it should at runtime. In fact the name of db, schema, table to create is dynamic at runtime, and would be used latter for DML.